# How can we fetch the height of title of a QTabWidget

Tags: qt, qt4.8, qtabwidget

Is there any possible way to fetch the height of the title bar that comes in a QTabWidget?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
QTabWidget *myTabWidget = new QTabWidget();
int titleBarHeight = myTabWidget->tabBar->height();
```

Comment: thanks for your help but i am getting error while running this code
 error: 'QTabBar* QTabWidget::tabBar() const' is protected

kindly suggest what to do/

Comment: well, ok, sry. I didn't tried it before. just create a new class, which is a child of QTabWidget. Then create myTabWidget as an instance of the new class. It worked, when I tried it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-implement the tabSizeHint() method in a subclass of QTabBar. Then you can get the size if you wish too and resize your QTabWidget's tabs to whatever size you would like. Hope this helps. Cheers.